# How to share generated google graph on facebook

Tags: graph, virtualization, facebook-share

I have generated a graph using Google line graph from database now I have to share the graph on Facebook,Twitter,..

Please suggest any idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can export google charts as png image. [source](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing)